# How can I logout of any guards with one method?

Tags: laravel

I have one method which I use to logout of any sessons/guards at the moment, the problem is I have to define each one which at the moment is fine as there is only two.

I would like to know if there is a way to make this simpler (aside from just destroying all session data).

```
Route::get('/logout', function () {
    Auth::logout();
    Auth::guard('business_user')->logout();
    return redirect()->route('home');
})->name('user.logout');
```

Comment: Not a great solution but since guards are stored as an array in the config/auth.php you could grab all your guards with `Config::get('auth.guards')` and loop through them and log then out of each one. You can do an also do `Auth::guard()->check()` before we logging out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do something like this in my test suites when resetting the auth manager between web calls. You get the list of defined guards from the config file, and then you loop through those guards and call `logout()` on the guards that support the `logout()` method. Comments in the code.

```
Route::get('/logout', function () {
    // Get a list of all of the defined guards.
    $guards = array_keys(config('auth.guards'));

    // Loop through each guard and logout.
    foreach ($guards as $guard) {
        $guard = app('auth')->guard($guard);

        // Not all guard types have a logout method. The SessionGuard (web) does,
        // the TokenGuard (api) does not. Only call the method if it exists
        // on the guard.
        if (method_exists($guard, 'logout')) {
            $guard->logout();
        }
    }

    return redirect()->route('home');
})->name('user.logout');
```